# default position of windows/programs (xubuntu 18.04)

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, xfce

At work I have a dual monitor set up, with emacs etc on the primary display and evince etc on the second display.  Under

```
 xfce->window manager->focus
```

I set

```
focus follows mouse
```

With that, if I fire up a program (emacs/browser/etc) generally the new object will appear in the same monitor as the current position of the cursor.  The one frequent offender is google-chrome, which has a mind of its own and insists on showing up on monitor #2.

Recently I added a third monitor.  And now google-chrome and evince will show up on the 3rd monitor instead!

Question:  (#1) What I can do to "reset" the default position of various programs so they appear in the same monitor as the current position of cursor?

(#2) What can I do to force a program/window to always appear on the primary display?

I know that #1 and #2 are not always compatible, so I guess it would be "if I can't make #1 work, then I'll go with #2".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is rather little user control on the default placement of windows in floating window managers. The application itself can have control on window placements, and that is how some applications remember their size or insist appearing in the same spot the next time.

> (#1) What I can do to "reset" the default position of various programs
> so they appear in the same monitor as the current position of cursor?

There is probably little you can do here. Programs controlling their window store their information each in their own way, using dconf or using a configuration file...

> (#2) What can I do to force a program/window to always appear on the
> primary display?

This can be coped with, but the solution depends on some old utilities requiring you to manually set up some configuration files. The utilities `devilspie` and `devilspie2`, a successor with a different syntax, are little daemons that watch the creation of new windows. Then, they automatically adapt the window according to a rule you define.

Thus, you could set any new window to appear on the primary monitor. You can also have specific rules for particular windows: you could have your browser always appear on the third monitor in full screen without window decorations, etc.